# Cannot Play DVD - Unknown filesystem?

Tags: dvd

I have a DVD that was created on a some DVD recorder/player box. I am trying to grab the files off of it so I can do video editing of the footage.

My problem is I cannot read the DVD. It is detected as a blank disk on Windows and OS X. Linux won't find the disk to mount it. The DVD plays perfectly fine on a standalone DVD player (Toshiba was the one I tried).

Since I can't mount the disk with Ubuntu, I am guessing there is filesystem on the disk which cannot be read. Are there some packages out there I can install to give me a shot at reading this filesystem and ripping off the data?

EDIT: 
After running `vlc /dev/sr0` dmesg shows the following

```
[ 5001.607820] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5001.607827] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5001.607831] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5001.607844] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5001.607846] Info fld=0x0
[ 5001.607847] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5001.607849] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5001.607850] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5001.607851] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 5001.607854] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 5001.607857] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[ 5001.607858] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
[ 5004.471249] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5004.471255] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5004.471259] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5004.471261] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5004.471266] Info fld=0x0
[ 5004.471269] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5004.471273] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5004.471277] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5004.471278] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[ 5004.471289] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 5004.471294] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[ 5007.339915] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5007.339920] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5007.339924] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5007.339926] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5007.339931] Info fld=0x1
[ 5007.339934] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5007.339938] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5007.339941] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5007.339943] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[ 5007.339954] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4
[ 5007.339958] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
[ 5010.208395] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5010.208401] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5010.208405] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5010.208407] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5010.208422] Info fld=0x0
[ 5010.208423] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5010.208425] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5010.208426] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5010.208426] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 5010.208430] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 5010.208431] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[ 5010.208432] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
[ 5010.208435] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 2
[ 5010.208436] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 3
[ 5010.208437] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 4
[ 5010.208438] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 5
[ 5010.208439] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 6
[ 5010.208440] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 7
[ 5013.076649] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5013.076655] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5013.076658] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5013.076661] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5013.076665] Info fld=0x0
[ 5013.076668] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5013.076672] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5013.076676] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5013.076678] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[ 5013.076688] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 5013.076693] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[ 5015.939911] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5015.939916] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5015.939920] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5015.939922] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5015.939927] Info fld=0x1
[ 5015.939930] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5015.939934] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5015.939937] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5015.939939] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[ 5015.939950] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4
[ 5015.939954] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
[ 5018.813705] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5018.813710] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5018.813714] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5018.813716] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5018.813721] Info fld=0x100
[ 5018.813724] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5018.813728] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5018.813731] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5018.813733] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00
[ 5018.813744] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
[ 5018.813749] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 256
[ 5018.813753] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 257
[ 5021.681952] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5021.681957] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5021.681961] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5021.681963] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5021.681968] Info fld=0x100
[ 5021.681971] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5021.681976] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5021.681979] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5021.681981] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00
[ 5021.681992] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
[ 5021.681996] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 256
[ 5024.550795] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5024.550801] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5024.550805] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5024.550808] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5024.550813] Info fld=0x101
[ 5024.550816] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5024.550820] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5024.550823] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5024.550825] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 01 00
[ 5024.550836] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1028
[ 5024.550842] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 257
[ 5027.419831] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5027.419837] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5027.419840] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5027.419843] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5027.419848] Info fld=0x100
[ 5027.419851] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5027.419854] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5027.419858] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5027.419860] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00
[ 5027.419871] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
[ 5027.419876] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 256
[ 5030.288536] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5030.288542] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5030.288545] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5030.288548] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5030.288552] Info fld=0x101
[ 5030.288555] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5030.288559] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5030.288563] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5030.288565] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 01 00
[ 5030.288576] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1028
[ 5030.288580] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 257
[ 5033.147861] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5033.147866] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5033.147870] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5033.147872] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5033.147877] Info fld=0x0
[ 5033.147890] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5033.147891] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5033.147892] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5033.147893] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 5033.147896] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 5033.147898] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[ 5033.147899] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
[ 5036.016614] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5036.016619] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5036.016623] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5036.016625] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5036.016630] Info fld=0x0
[ 5036.016633] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5036.016637] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5036.016640] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5036.016642] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[ 5036.016653] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 5036.016657] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[ 5038.885062] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5038.885067] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5038.885071] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5038.885073] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 5038.885078] Info fld=0x1
[ 5038.885081] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 5038.885085] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[ 5038.885088] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 5038.885090] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[ 5038.885101] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4
[ 5038.885105] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
```

Based on this my guess is to `dd` it into a .iso or .img file. Not sure if that will help the I/O errors though.

Comment: Why not do a Google search for "dvd ripper ubuntu?" https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/acidrip/

Comment: The packages needed depends on the disc, but the ones you need should be installed by default anyway. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of dmesg that appears when you put the disc in? (So (with the disc out), run `dmesg` and note lastest output, put the disc in and wait for it to spin up, run `dmesg` again and copy the new output)

Comment: @Zacharee1 - there are a few questions I think with such answers, example https://askubuntu.com/questions/147800/ripping-dvd-to-iso-accurately - though https://askubuntu.com/questions/15827/recovering-files-from-a-corrupt-cd-dvd/15839#15839 is a possible dupe

Comment: @Wilf dmesg and /var/log/syslog doesn't have any new messages in it when I put the DVD in the drive. I hear the drive spin up real quick and that is it.

Comment: Dunno then... you could try `vlc /dev/sr0` (or `/dev/dvd` whatever it is using - vlc will need to be installed) as that can work with some weird DVDs - you may want to make sure things like `libdvdcss` are installed (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs))

Comment: I just made sure the package was installed and VLC didn't work. The error was `libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.`

Comment: Just checked `dmesg` again. See the edit for the logs.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libdvdcss-dev` in a terminal